Calling functions and addressing arrays without operators
Is there a language where they write just ai for a[i] and sqrt2 for sqrt(2). I mean that arrays are treated like functions and calling a function does not need an operator.

Yes, K.
In K, you can select from an array a with the index i with just a i and you can apply a function like square root (%) as %2.
Try it!

It's good, but without a space, just "ai" would be better. Just forbid poly-lettered identifiers and no whitespaces will be needed. For longer names, you can take a table, for example, named _ , and just index it by a string: _'a variable', _'print '

@МаратРамазанов I believe K's little brother, K Junior does exactly that.
